# cocoon with devise not working Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cocoon-gem

i have a new problem, attempt to implement devise with cocoon and its not save in DB.  PLEASE HELP ME !!! :D

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :telefonos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :telefonos, :reject_if => :all_blank,  :allow_destroy => true

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

telefono model:

```
class Telefono < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In my users controller:

```
def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:telefonos_attributes: [:id, :telefono, :_destroy])
end
```

My AplicactionController

```
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

        def configure_permitted_parameters
             devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:nombre, :email, :password) }
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :current_password, :region_id, :ciudad_id, :nombre, telefonos_attributes: [:telefono, :user_id]) }
        end
     end
```

my edit view:

```
<h3>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h3>

  <%= simple_form_for resource, :as => resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put} do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :nombre, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.association :region, :include_blank => false %>
      <%= f.association :ciudad, :include_blank => false %>
    </div>
    <h1>Telefono</h1>
    <div id="telefonos">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :telefonos do |t| %>
        <%= render 'telefono_fields', :f => telefono %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add telefono', f, :telefonos %>
    </div>
  </div>
<%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

my _telefono_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :telefono %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove telefono", f %>
```

Regards,

Comment: In the `telefonos_attributes` you should have two more attributes `id` and `_destroy`. This is just for your info. This may be the thing causing this issue or not. Just give it a try. And are you getting any error in console did you check?

Comment: Thanks, but not generate error in console !! :/ You have any tutorial?

Comment: Unpermitted parameters: nombre, region_id, ciudad_id, telefonos_attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the same thing in some different way. I think you are getting `unpermitted parameters` because the application controller method is not working. But I have a solution for you. First run this command in your terminal:

```
rails g devise:controllers users
```

Instead of `users` you can use anything which will be the scope. Which means that it will generate the controllers of devise like this `app/controllers/users/[all controllers]`. Then in your routes file do like this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
```

What this will do that it will use the generated `registrations_controller`. Now in your generated registrations controller do like this. The below methods will be written in comments just uncomment them and edit according to your needs:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

protected


  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up){ |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :nombre) }
  end

  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update){ |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :current_password, :password_confirmation, :region_id, :ciudad_id, :nombre, telefonos_attributes: [:id, :telefono, :user_id], :_destroy) }
  end
```

I am assuming that while sign up you require only the attributes mentioned. If you require any other attributes too then add them.

The devise by default requires `current_password` for making any edit. If you are using the devise generated views then it should contain a field for `current_password`. But I don't see it anywhere in your form. So if you want to skip this and don't want the user to enter password each time then in the `registrations_controller` add this in the `protected` scope only:

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
  resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps you too.